# 130 GB Syslog files

Tags: syslog, plex

I have the same issue as many in this forum with the syslog file becoming massive in my case it gets to 130 GB in a day, when I looked into the file with the tail command I fund continuous remote connection attends from a couple different IP's this continuous attends is what is causing the file to become this big, this machine is my Plex media server where I have my movies, and this is the only function for this box, this is a problem for me because my primary drive is a 500gb SSD so after a couple of days I'm out of space. Any way I can block this connection attends without stopping my internet connection all along***

```
Jan 16 12:04:18 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: 16/01/2018 12:04:18 PM Client Protocol Version 3.4
Jan 16 12:04:18 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: 16/01/2018 12:04:18 PM Ignoring minor version mismatch
Jan 16 12:04:18 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: ** (vino-server:1964): WARNING **: Deferring authentication of '50-207-72-206-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net' for 5 seconds
Jan 16 12:04:24 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: ** (vino-server:1964): WARNING **: VNC authentication failure from '50-207-72-206-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net'
Jan 16 12:04:24 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: 16/01/2018 12:04:24 PM rfbAuthPasswordChecked: password check failed
Jan 16 12:04:24 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: 16/01/2018 12:04:24 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client 50-207-72-206-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net
Jan 16 12:04:24 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: 16/01/2018 12:04:24 PM   other clients:
Jan 16 12:04:24 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: 16/01/2018 12:04:24 PM      50-207-72-206-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net
Jan 16 12:04:24 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: message repeated 6 times: [ 16/01/2018 12:04:24 PM      50-207-72-206-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net]
Jan 16 12:04:24 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: 16/01/2018 12:04:24 PM      192.168.23.22
Jan 16 12:04:24 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: 16/01/2018 12:04:24 PM Client Protocol Version 3.4
Jan 16 12:04:24 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: 16/01/2018 12:04:24 PM Ignoring minor version mismatch
Jan 16 12:04:24 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: ** (vino-server:1964): WARNING **: Deferring authentication of '50-207-72-206-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net' for 5 seconds
Jan 16 12:04:29 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: 16/01/2018 12:04:29 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client 50-225-42-82-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net
Jan 16 12:04:29 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: 16/01/2018 12:04:29 PM   other clients:
Jan 16 12:04:29 T1-UHD-Movies-7PS1 gnome-session[1729]: 16/01/2018 12:04:29 PM      50-207-72-206-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net
```

Comment: You may try `iptables`, i.e. configure your firewall to drop attempts from a certain IP address. See [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-block-an-ip-on-my-linux-server/) for an example. E.g. `sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 206.72.207.50 -j DROP` See also [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/592061/346811)